# Oracle SQL missing keyword

Tags: oracle

Recently started with Oracle sql and I really can't understand what I'm doing wrong

```
Select  phones
From employees 
left join
(SELECT 
 Employees.manager_id
,COUNT(employees.employee_id)
From employees 
Group by employees.manager_id) AS "emc" on employees.manager_id = emc.manager_id
```

It returns error 00905 missing keyword and that "emc" is not colored like the other aliases but I have no idea why.

Comment: The query makes no sense and may be replaced with `SELECT phones FROM employees;`

Comment: @Akina it does make sense: if it works he'll learn (what's missing?).

Comment: @GerardH.Pille The query text is a reflection of the required logic for obtaining the result. I personally, in principle, do not understand what logic the author was trying to implement. What thoughts can give rise to such a query text? My advice is to reflect the formal logic of the query text. I just removed everything unnecessary.

Comment: @Akina, my first question has always been: "what does the author need?" Not what he/she wants, for he/she may be wrong, and only in the last instance "what did he/she write?"

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Agreed, but I do not see the answer for the former question. So we have to work with what we have...

Comment: The query is a lot more complex but even when I cut it down to this it keeps giving me the same result so for simplicity I post only that.

Comment: @Michael didn't you see my answer?  All you need to do is remove the parentheses from around the second select.

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille I tried that but removing the parentheses returns the same error and I really want to know what's the problem. Trying also with WITH but gives different error now.

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille It worked when I removed the parentheses and the AS. Thanks

Comment: I've corrected the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Michael, it looks like you got the answer you needed on your error. However, as others have said, what are you really trying to return from the query? The additional JOIN provides no added value to the results. As @Akina stated, `SELECT phones FROM employees;` would return the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with emc as (SELECT Employees.manager_id ,COUNT(employees.employee_id)
              From employees Group by employees.manager_id) 
Select phones From employees
left join emc
    on employees.manager_id = emc.manager_id;
```

or

```
Select phones From employees left join
SELECT Employees.manager_id ,COUNT(employees.employee_id)
From employees Group by employees.manager_id emc
on employees.manager_id = emc.manager_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:

1. There shouldn't be any `as` keyword for table aliases.
2. `"emc"` and `emc` are two different things.
3. `count(employees.employee_id)` in the inner query isn't used anywhere. If it was used, you would probably want to give it an alias such as `employee_count`. (Also `count(*)` is the standard expression for counting rows, but it will give the same result.) But if you don't need it, there is point in the `group by`, or indeed the whole join.

Therefore a fixed version might be:

```
select phones
from   employees
       left join
            ( select employees.manager_id
              from   employees
              group  by employees.manager_id ) emc
            on employees.manager_id = emc.manager_id;
```

"phones" seems an odd name for a column, and it isn't present in the Oracle `HR` sample schema, but perhaps you have it in yours.

Since you're starting out, it might be worth thinking about whether you prefer `SELECT`, `Select` or `select`, and using that style consistently. (In my view, `SELECT` is a bad habit from the 1970s, and `Select` is an abomination.)